# android animations for view flipper?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

i am looking for an animation for a view flipper.

How would i go about animating so that the view basically goes back to front when a button is pressed. where there is a map view on one side and a listview on the other.

i have the above working except for the animation . could someone help or explain android animations to me

edit added here

here is some code for animation for rotation, how could i implment this in xml

```
public class Rotate3dAnimation extends Animation {
    private final float mFromDegrees;
    private final float mToDegrees;
    private final float mCenterX;
    private final float mCenterY;
    private final float mDepthZ;
    private final boolean mReverse;
    private Camera mCamera;

/**
 * Creates a new 3D rotation on the Y axis. The rotation is defined by its
 * start angle and its end angle. Both angles are in degrees. The rotation
 * is performed around a center point on the 2D space, definied by a pair
 * of X and Y coordinates, called centerX and centerY. When the animation
 * starts, a translation on the Z axis (depth) is performed. The length
 * of the translation can be specified, as well as whether the translation
 * should be reversed in time.
 *
 * @param fromDegrees the start angle of the 3D rotation
 * @param toDegrees the end angle of the 3D rotation
 * @param centerX the X center of the 3D rotation
 * @param centerY the Y center of the 3D rotation
 * @param reverse true if the translation should be reversed, false otherwise
 */
public Rotate3dAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees,
        float centerX, float centerY, float depthZ, boolean reverse) {
    mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
    mToDegrees = toDegrees;
    mCenterX = centerX;
    mCenterY = centerY;
    mDepthZ = depthZ;
    mReverse = reverse;
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    mCamera = new Camera();
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
    float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

    final float centerX = mCenterX;
    final float centerY = mCenterY;
    final Camera camera = mCamera;

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

    camera.save();
    if (mReverse) {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * interpolatedTime);
    } else {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));
    }
    camera.rotateY(degrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do but you can lookup wiEngine for Android SDK, at the transitions example... take a look at the code thought the documentation is in chinese, you can simply read the code.

Also take a look at Chet Haase blog for some tips, http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/ he has a bunch of stuff related to animation. Targeting API level12 that would take just about one line of code using the method objectToAnimate.rotateYBy(360).setDuration(250f)